# spring starter project - term definitions

Tags: spring

I'm just starting out to learn Spring.  I've acquired 2 books from Apress on the subject and I've download the latest STS version.  When I start the wizard to create a new Spring Starter Project I am presented with a screen to select how I want to set up the project.  Most of what is presented is self-explanatory - except for 4 boxes:  **Group, Artifact, Version** and **Package**. I'm not able to find in Spring or in my books what these fields are for and how they relate to each other and the project I want to create.  For instance, it shows a suggestion of "demo" for the package and I though packages where in the format of "org.mycomp.appname" which is what they show for group?  I'm confused.  And why does it use 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT for version?  Shouldn't it be more like 0.0.1?

Can anyone point me to where these fields would be described?

Comment: This is the top result when you Google for the four words you emphasised: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the fields for the Maven or Gradle project you are creating. 
Group ID is usually used to group modules from larger projects, Artifact ID is the ID of the specific module.
SNAPSHOT versions are development versions in Maven, so as long as you aren't building a release, your project has always a SNAPSHOT version.
As for the Java package, you are completely free in your choice. Convention is to use any kind of domain name (usually the domain name of the company), but if you don't have one because you are developing yourself, you can choose whatever you want.